# Get the Time in " Ago" form according to respective time regions using date and time from DB

Tags: php, datetime, time, datetimeoffset

I have time and date from my DB and I tried to echo the same in "minutes/hrs Ago" form.

like if I have text posted 2 days back, it shows as "2 days ago" by taking the time and date.

The code works fine, However, it doesn't vary for different time regions.

my code goes as:

```
<?php
$mytimestring = '2018-02-27 07:57:19';
function humanTiming ($time)
        {

            $time = time() - $time; // to get the time since that moment
            $time = ($time<1)? 1 : $time;
            $tokens = array (
                31536000 => 'year',
                2592000 => 'month',
                604800 => 'week',
                86400 => 'day',
                3600 => 'hour',
                60 => 'minute',
                1 => 'second'
            );

            foreach ($tokens as $unit => $text) {
                if ($time < $unit) continue;
                $numberOfUnits = floor($time / $unit);
                return $numberOfUnits.' '.$text.(($numberOfUnits>1)?'s':'');
            }

        }

echo humanTiming( strtotime($mytimestring) );

?>
```

It only works for that given time and doesn't vary for IST or any other.

Any helps is greatly appreciated..

Comment: Your DBMS is MySql? You should specify it.

Comment: its Msqli @shadowsheep

Comment: Where exactly would you get the timezone information from? Do you expect for it to adjust automagically, or do you have a timezone name or offset from the user somewhere?

Comment: no i need it to adjust automatically . as a user from india login in and see's every post as per his timeline IST, while a user from US logs in he will see each post as per his timeline EST.@deceze

Comment: Then your first issue is to automagically detect the user's timezone, which is something of a problem. You could try to detect the browser's timezone using Javascript, but that's going to be asynchronous and won't be available on the first request. You could try geolocation via IP, but that's not terribly reliable or accurate. Your best bet is to ask the user for their preferred timezone, or to render it in the browser using Javascript and local browser information.

Comment: So, in my code, where is the code that is considering the time zone of particular region,. >